# Prove that for any 2 events A and B , $P(A) + P(B) - 1 ≤ P(AB) ≤ P(A) ≤ P(A\cup B) ≤ P(A) + P(B)$

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

I want to prove (∩)⩾()+()−1.

How can I simplify the following proof?

(∩)=()−(∩)=()−1+(∪)=()−1+()+()−(∩)=()+()+(∩)−1⩾()+()−1

*please ignore the body of the question i copied it from somewhere else in order to publish the question

Comment: here P(a\cupb) means p(aUb)

Comment: Drawing the Venn diagram will easily solve this for you.

Comment: You can use math typesetting in your posts. This is easier and renders more nicely than copy-pasting from somewhere. More information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Sycorax sure i'll give it a shot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noting that,
\begin{align*}
P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B), 
\end{align*}
and that since $P(A\cup B)$ is a probability,
\begin{align*}
P(A\cup B) \leq 1.
\end{align*}
So,
\begin{align*}
P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B) &\leq 1\\
\Rightarrow P(A) + P(B) - 1 &\leq P(A\cap B). \hspace{1cm} \square
\end{align*}